# "Scanner closed" message after running

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a program that creates a webgraph from text files. Every Time I run it I get the same message that says "Scanner Closed."

```
//constant final variables
public static final String PAGES_FILE = "pages.txt";
public static final String LINKS_FILE = "links.txt";
// webgraph object var
private WebGraph web;
// searchEngine constructor.
public SearchEngine() throws FileNotFoundException {
    web = WebGraph.buildFromFiles(PAGES_FILE, LINKS_FILE);
}
```

Scanner Portion

```
try {       
System.out.println("Loading WebGraph data...");
SearchEngine engine = new SearchEngine();
System.out.println("Success!");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I have the scanner.close() right after the try block which contains all the possible user inputs. I have also attached an image of what should be happening once I run the program. Any ideas what could be going wrong? If any other code is needed I can provide that.[Sample Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiJoZ.png)
Here is the image of what I am getting [My Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo0l8.png)

This is the code for the "buildFromFiles"

```
public static WebGraph buildFromFiles(String pagesFile, String linksFile)
  throws IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException {
WebGraph webGraph = new WebGraph();
File filePages = new File(pagesFile);
File fileLinks = new File(linksFile);
if (filePages.exists() && fileLinks.exists() && filePages.isFile() && fileLinks.isFile()) {
  Scanner pageScanner = new Scanner(filePages);
  while (pageScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] pageData = pageScanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    String url = pageData[0];
    ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i < pageData.length; i++) {
      keywords.add(pageData[i]);
    }
    webGraph.addPage(url, keywords);
  }
  pageScanner.close();
  Scanner linkScanner = new Scanner(fileLinks);
  while (linkScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] linkData = pageScanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    webGraph.addLink(linkData[0], linkData[1]);
  }
  linkScanner.close();
} else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
return webGraph;
```

}

Comment: Please post exception and relevant code.

Comment: Do not close `scanner` for `System.in` - it can not be re-opened

Comment: In your second image, we can see that there is a "_Loading WebGraph data..._" message but not the "_Success!_" part. What are you doing in the `WebGraph.buildFromFiles`? The message comes from there. Or is it a third party content?

Comment: removing scanner.close() still gives me the same message

Comment: using WebGraph.buildFromFiles I am trying to build WebGraphs from the data in the txt files in the library. I am attaching my buildFromFiles code right now